# Standard Error lines intersecting

Tags: r, plot, lme4, standard-error

I am currently running lmer() for a dataset in r with the following structure:

```
avgcobint=lmer(scale.logcptplus1 ~ scale.logdepth + scale.avgcobb + scale.logdepth:scale.avgcobb + (1|location) + (1|Fyear), data=cpt, REML=TRUE)
```

and receive the following summary for the fixed effects:

```
Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                  -0.04868    0.15425  -0.316
scale.logdepth               -0.32668    0.06168  -5.297
scale.avgcobb                 0.11014    0.10478   1.051
scale.logdepth:scale.avgcobb  0.11689    0.06086   1.921
```

I then predict my real value estimates from the log and scaled variables with this equation for the median depth (14)...which is the correct real values line in the graph below:

```
resultmeddepth14= -0.04868 + exp((-0.32668) * ((depth_median-mean(cpt$logdepth))/sd(cpt$logdepth))) + (0.11014 * ((cobb_range - mean(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))/sd(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))) + (0.11689 *(exp(((depth_median-mean(cpt$logdepth))/sd(cpt$logdepth))))*((cobb_range - mean(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))/sd(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm)))
```

[lmer real value estimates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkaQN.png)

BUT when I add the +/- one standard error lines using these equations:

MINUS SE

```
resultmeddepthminus= (-0.04868-0.15425) + exp((-0.32668-0.06168) * ((depth_median-mean(cpt$logdepth))/sd(cpt$logdepth))) + ((0.11014-0.10478) * ((cobb_range - mean(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))/sd(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))) + ((0.11689-0.06086) *(exp(((depth_median-mean(cpt$logdepth))/sd(cpt$logdepth))))*((cobb_range - mean(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))/sd(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm)))
```

PLUS SE

```
resultmeddepthplus= (-0.04868+0.15425) + exp((-0.32668+0.06168) * ((depth_median-mean(cpt$logdepth))/sd(cpt$logdepth))) + ((0.11014+0.10478) * ((cobb_range - mean(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))/sd(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))) + ((0.11689+0.06086) *(exp(((depth_median-mean(cpt$logdepth))/sd(cpt$logdepth))))*((cobb_range - mean(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm))/sd(cpt$avgsummercobbleareakm)))
```

I have this graph:
[lmer real estimates +/- one SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwFPX.jpg)

and the intersection of all the lines is at an x-value of 0.068341709

Why are the SE lines intersecting?  Whats happening here and how can/should I fix it?

Comment: It looks like one of the terms in your estimation of the SE shrinks it to zero around x = 0.07. It's hard to say more without replication.

Comment: There is now a `predict` method for merMod objects with a type="response" argument so it's not clear to me why you want to construct your own version, especially so since I think you are failing to take into account covariances properly.